# After downloading Tweepy I don't know where to locate it

Tags: python

I have downloaded Tweepy, and I locate its folder in the following path, where I have other libraries such as Pygame and swampy:

```
C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages
```

… but when I import it – even in the command line – to make sure that the installation was successfully done, it says:

```
import tweepy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\tweepy\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
from tweepy.api import API
File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 8, in <module>
from tweepy.binder import bind_api
File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 22, in <module>
raise ImportError, "Can't load a json library"
ImportError: Can't load a json library
```

Comment: you need to follow installation instructions for tweepy: https://code.google.com/p/tweepy/

Comment: python packages can be kind of a mess and vary quite a bit in requirements and needs in regard to your python path. That is why it is recommended that you use http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip or http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

Comment: Dmirty,
I downloaded Tweety from the link you provided, but for me it wasn't clear where to locate it after that!!

Comment: a paid nerd, thanx for the response..

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the suggestion; I working on it right now, hope this will solve my problem..

Comment: `python25` doesn't have a json module. Upgrading to the latest 2.x would help, if you can, or see if tweepy supports any other json libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because your python installation 2.5 does not have any json libraries that Tweepy is looking for.  Tweeppy currently tries to use the `simplejson` library, the `json` library or the `django.utils` library, if you don't have then it throws the error you see now.